# Check for inequality in Eve query?

Tags: mongodb, eve, nosql

I have a MongoDB set up to use the Eve REST HTTP interface.

I'm trying to query my database for all count values that are not 0.

I have obviously followed enough of the documentation to know that the following:

```
http://localhost:5000/machinesFull?where={%22count%22:0}
```

will give me the opposite of what I am looking for.

Is there a way to show all entries where "count" is not 0?

Comment: Will it accept arbitrary criteria in the query string? then `"count": { "$ne": 0 }` is what you need.

Comment: That's exactly how it's done!  Thank you!!  You should post it as an answer so that I can vote for it. :)

Comment: This was my first question on Stack Overflow, so I apparently can't give you a vote yet, but I selected it as the answer.  Thanks again, Sergio!

Comment: Don't worry about the vote, I have plenty of those :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Eve, but judging from your example, it will accept arbitrary criteria in the query string.

In this case, use the mongodb syntax for inequality queries:

```
{ "count": { "$ne": 0 } }
```

Comment: Right. All mongo operators except the blacklisted ones (`$regex` and `%where` by default, which you can opt to whitelist) are allowed.